# Problems restoring an Azure block blob snapshot to another container with Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, blob, storage, restore

I'm trying to restore yesterday's snapshot for all data in an azure blob storage container.

```
$StorageAccountName = "SOURCE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT"
$StorageAccountKey = "STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY"
$ContainerName = "SOURCE_CONTAINER"
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey 
$ListBlob = Get-AzureStorageBlob –Context $Ctx -Container $ContainerName | Where-Object {$_.ICloudBlob.IsSnapshot -and $_.SnapshotTime -ne $null -and (($_.SnapshotTime.localdatetime).ToString('yyyyMMdd') -eq $ySnap)}
$DestContainerName = "DESTINATION_CONTAINER"

for ($i=0; $i -lt $ListBlob.length; $i++) {
    $snapshot=$ListBlob[$i]
    [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob] $snapshot.ICloudBlob
    Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy –Context $Ctx -ICloudBlob $snapshot -DestContainer $DestContainerName
}
```

Everything works up until:

`[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob] $snapshot.ICloudBlob`

The error i receive is:

```
Cannot convert the "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob" value of type "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob" to type "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob".
At line:1 char:1
+ [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob] $snapshot.ICloudBlob
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
```

How would i cast $snapshot from a CloudBlockBlob to a CloudBlob? Or am i going about this the wrong way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whelp i'm a fool. The solution was to use the .ICloudBlob property instead of trying to cast it to a CloudBlob.

ie.

```
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy –Context $Ctx -ICloudBlob $snapshot.ICloudBlob -DestContainer $DestContainerName
```